# Prevent Windows from rapidly repeating keys (due to a faulty laptop keyboard)

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, keyboard

I have a laptop with a keyboard that will randomly repeat keys (might be a shorted-out keyboard). I have tried messing with the key hold-down time settings, but that did not fix it. It's as if when I press a key, it is very quickly pressing the key up and down rapidly, not a "being held down" issue but a "being pressed rapidly issue."

Is it possible to set a minimum length of time between repeating key presses on Windows?

I'm trying to make this laptop stretch as long as it can.

Example: Typing "Is it possible" results in "Isss it posssibllle"

Comment: The technical term is "debouncing". I'm not sure if you can do that in Windows. Consider disabling the keyboard and using an external one.

Comment: I was doing that but got tired of carrying an external keyboard to coffee shops :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Keyboard Chatter Blocker](https://github.com/mcmonkeyprojects/KeyboardChatterBlocker)**, a free and open-source software that can do that — prevent Windows from rapidly repeating keys AKA "keyboard chatter". You can use it to ensure that your keyboard inputs are registered accurately and without any unintended repetitions.

After installing it, go to ‘Configure Keys’ → ‘Add Key’ → then press the affected key. Set the ‘Chatter Threshold’ (in milliseconds) according to your preference, then check the ‘Enable’ box. You may also want to set the ‘Global Chatter Threshold’ to ‘0’ so that it does not affect all keys, and check the ‘Start With Windows’ box to make it run on startup.

The UI should look like this after you configure the software. In this screenshot, I have set it to prevent keyboard chatter for the Enter/Return key:

[image: screenshot of Keyboard Chatter Blocker UI once a key has been configured]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution shortly after posting (at least, I think, it seems to work a bit better).

Using the advice from *[FilterKeys Setter... for a faster key repeat (in Windows)](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=41881.0)*, I ended up changing the registry and setting the bounce time to a lower value, 20 ms.

[image]

Comment: Sorry the pic shows 10 ms (BounceTime) but I was still getting some bouncing so I increased to 20 and it seems to work so far.